# How to customize Android action bar with search button

Tags: android-actionbar

I want to create a custom action bar in my app like the Play Store Action bar so I can have some Back to Home and Search buttons. I'm beginner to Android development and don't know how can I do it.

How can I add these buttons and have this action bar remain in all activity layouts?
Also, how can I create a class that universally handles searches and click events from this action bar without hardcoding in each activity?

Comment: Hi, I don't know anything about android development myself, but I think the experts around here will need you to provide some details about what specific android version you are developing for and what development technologies/languages you are using.  Please post some more info.  Thanks!

Comment: it must run at least in android 2.1 .

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem.
for creating action bar , my solution is creating a layout and disable native action bar in style.xml by this tag

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

then use your own layout instead of native layout.

for handle action bar universaly in all activities instead of writing repetitious codes it's better to create a base class that extends from Activity class and use this class as parent class of other activities instead of using Activity as parent. then write methods in parent class for handle action bar like click event and etc...

Best Regards
Ali